# Merging two pyramid tile sets (directory)?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles, gdal-merge, image-pyramids

I was searching on the Internet about the merging of GeoTIFF tiles (pyramid tiles) generated by `gdal2tiles`.

Below are the steps I performed

1. Downloaded tif-files.
2. Converted tif to vrt (below command)

```
gdalbuildvrt temp_intermediate/merged.vrt *.tif 

gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba temp_intermediate/merged.vrt temp_intermediate/merged-4326.vrt
```

3. Translated vrt to pyramid tiles (below command)

```
gdal2tiles.py -z '14-21'  temp_intermediate/merged-4326.vrt  output/
```

Now if I get another set of tif-files and performed the same operation I'll be having two pyramid tiles directory (lets say `outout1` and `outout2` directories) and I want to merge them. How could this be done?